# Problema con bucle for de asincronía

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb

Estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda accediendo a dos bases de datos (de MongoDB) en una misma función, y utilizando un bucle for, sin embargo, me da un problema que identifico como de asincronía. Adjunto el código a continuación. Comentar que son el modelo.js y persistencia.js (mi objeto de operaciones con la base de datos).

Objeto modelo.js

```
this.obtenerAgendaActividades = function (nick, curso, asignatura, callback) {
    var aHechas=[];
    var aNoHechas=[]
    var ju = this;
    var cb = callback;
    this.persistencia.obtenerEjerciciosCriterio({ dificultad: curso, asignatura: asignatura}, function (actividades) {
        if (!actividades) {
            console.log("No hay actividades para ese curso y asignatura")
            cb({ 'actividades': [] });
        }
        else {
            console.log('445 '+actividades)
            
                    
                for (var i=0; i<actividades.length;i++) {
                    //setTimeout(function () {
                    // Muestra correctamente los dos console
                    console.log(i)
                    console.log('nick: '+nick+' nombre Activiadad: '+actividades[i].nombre)
                    ju.persistencia.encontrarResultadosCriterio({nick:nick,nombreEjercicio:actividades[i].nombre},function(resultados){
                        // Muestra i = actividades.length + 1, por tanto actividades[i]=undefined
                        console.log(i)
                        if(resultados){
                            console.log('entro hechas')
                            aHechas.push(actividades[i]);
                            console.log(actividadesHechas);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('entro no hechas')
                            aNoHechas.push(actividades[i]);
                            console.log(actividadesNoHechas);
                        }
                    });
                    //}.bind(this), 2000);
                
                }
                cb({'hechas':actividadesHechas, 'noHechas': actividadesNoHechas});

            
        }
    });

}
```

Objeto persistencia.js - Muestro solo las funciones que uso en esta operación

```
this.obtenerEjerciciosCriterio = function (criterio, callback) {
    obtenerCriterio(this.ejerciciosCol, criterio, callback);
 };
 this.encontrarResultadosCriterio = function (criterio, callback) {
    encontrar(this.resultadosCol, criterio, callback);
};
function encontrar(coleccion, criterio, callback) {
  coleccion.find(criterio).toArray(function (error, usr) {
    if (usr.length == 0) {
      console.log('Elemento no encontrado')
      callback(undefined);
    }
    else {
      callback(usr[0]);
      console.log("Elemento encontrado: "+usr[0]._id)
                
    }
  });
};
function obtenerCriterio(coleccion, criterio, callback) {
  coleccion.find(criterio).toArray(function (error, col) {
    callback(col);
  })
}
```

El problema como comento en el código, es al entrar en el bucle for, puesto que no le da tiempo a realizar encontrarResultadoCriterio, ya que i pasa a ser actividades.length+1, y por tanto, las actividades que me añade a los array son undefined.

///////////////ACTUALIZACIÓN CODIGO APLICANDO BIND///////////////////

```
this.obtenerAgendaActividades = function (nick, curso, asignatura, callback) {
    var ju = this;
    var cb = callback;
    this.persistencia.obtenerEjerciciosCriterio({ dificultad: curso, asignatura: asignatura}, function (actividades) {
        if (!actividades) {
            console.log("No hay actividades para ese curso y asignatura")
            cb({ 'actividades': [] });
        }
        else {
            console.log('445 '+actividades)
            
            firstCall().then(function(actividades) {
                for (var i=0; i<actividades.length; i++) {
                    console.log("Iteration:" + i)
            
                    secondCall(extractedMethod.bind({ nick: nick, nombreEjercicio: actividades[i].nombre }))
                }
            })      
         }
    });

}

function firstCall(howMany) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            function done() {
                resolve(Array.from(Array(howMany).keys()))
            }
    
            setTimeout(done, 1000)
        })
    }
    
    
    function secondCall(cb) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            function done() {
                cb()
                resolve("Done")
            }
    
            setTimeout(done, 1000)
        })
    }

    function extractedMethod() {
        var actividadesHechas=[];
        var actividadesNoHechas=[]
        var ju = this;
        
        console.log(this.nombreEjercicio)
        
        // No puedo acceder a persistencia  ju.persistencia.encontrarResultadosCriterio({nick:this.nick,nombreEjercicio:this.nombreEjercicio},function(resultados){
                            console.log(this)
                            if(resultados){
                                console.log('entro hechas')
                                actividadesHechas.push(actividades[this]);
                                console.log(actividadesHechas);
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log('entro no hechas')
                                actividadesoHechas.push(actividades[this]);
                                console.log(actividadesNoHechas);
                            }
                        });
        console.log("Inside iteration: " + this)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Javascript cuando pasas variables a una función estas variables se pasan como  punteros de memoria (by reference) en vez de ser copias del valor (by value).

Lo cual significa que tu función interna está referenciando a la misma posición de memoria que tu `for`. Por lo cual en cuanto el `for` cambia el valor este también cambia para tu callback.

Lo cual produce el efecto que estás viendo.

Un ejemplo simple para que sea mas visual:

```js
function firstCall(howMany = 10) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function done() {
            resolve(Array.from(Array(howMany).keys()))
        }

        setTimeout(done, 1000)
    })
}


function secondCall(cb) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function done() {
            cb()
            resolve("Done")
        }

        setTimeout(done, 1000)
    })
}


firstCall().then(function(activities) {
    for (var i=0; i<activities.length; i++) {
        console.log("Iteration:" + i)

        secondCall(function() {
            console.log("Inside iteration: " + i)
        })
    }
})
```

Una forma de afrontar el problema es usar `bind` lo cual creará una copia de la función con ese parámetro añadido.

```js
function firstCall(howMany = 10) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function done() {
            resolve(Array.from(Array(howMany).keys()))
        }

        setTimeout(done, 1000)
    })
}


function secondCall(cb) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function done() {
            cb()
            resolve("Done")
        }

        setTimeout(done, 1000)
    })
}


function extractedMethod() {
    console.log("Inside iteration: " + this)
}

firstCall().then(function(activities) {
    for (var i=0; i<activities.length; i++) {
        console.log("Iteration:" + i)

        secondCall(extractedMethod.bind(i))
    }
})
```

Nótese que en `extractedMethod` estamos llamando a `this` no a `i` eso es porque `bind` cambia quien es el `this` para esa función.
También podrías usar `call` o `apply` para hacer algo similar.

De todas formas JS se está moviendo para evitar el llamado "callback hell" y también dejar de pensar tanto en que valor tiene `this` en este contexto, ya que es motivo de muchos bugs y errores.

Así que solo me queda añadir que, si tienes la posibilidad, es mucho mas simple utilizar `Promises` directamente en vez de pasar callbacks.

Si puedes hacer eso no tienes que pensar en hacer un binding o que valore tendrá this en esa llamada etc.. y la forma de ejecutar comportamientos es encadenar callbacks.

Ejemplo

```js
function firstCall(howMany = 10) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function done() {
            resolve(Array.from(Array(howMany).keys()))
        }

        setTimeout(done, 1000)
    })
}


function secondCall(number) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function done() {
            resolve("Your iteration was: " + number)
        }

        setTimeout(done, 1000)
    })
}

firstCall().then(function(activities) {
    for (var i=0; i<activities.length; i++) {
        console.log("Iteration:" + i)

        secondCall(i).then(function(message) {
            console.log(message)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Entiendo los ejemplos que me das, pues es lo que me pasa y lo que quiero. Sin embargo, a la hora de aplicarlo a mi código estoy teniendo dificultades. Estoy usando el primer ejemplo que das con `callbacks`. Llamo a `firstCall () `dentro de mi función `obtenerAgendaActividades`. Y lo que tendría dentro del for (la llamada a persistencia con el if de dentro), lo pongo en `extractedMethod.` Sin embargo necesito los parámetros nick y nombreEjercicio, y no sé como hacerlo.. si pasarlo por aqui `secondCall(extractedMethod.bind(i))` y dejar `secondCall `tal cual

Comment: Si. lo que harías sería pasar en el bind un objecto `.bind({ nick: nick, nombreEjercicio: nombreEjercicio })` y en el "extractedMethod" lo llamarías usando `this.nick` y `this.extractedMethod`

Comment: He editado la pregunta aplicando los cambios de bind. El problema que tengo ahora es por los callbacks, de como pasar lo que era para mi ` cb({'hechas':actividadesHechas, 'noHechas': actividadesNoHechas});`. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Otro problema que he detectado, es que puesto que this es otro, no puedo acceder al objeto persistencia.